# curl: fill in web form and retrieve content

Tags: bash, curl, webforms, wget

I want to use bash script auto fill in the web form on the website: http://www.epncb.oma.be/_productsservices/coord_trans/index.php, and retrieve the result from output text box.

I tried:

`curl -d from_frame_in="values"  -d from_epoch_year="values" -d from_epoch_decimal="values" -d inputvalues="values" -d to_frame_out="values" -d to_epoch_year="values" -d to_epoch_decimal="values" -d transform_button="values" "$websiteurl"`.

However, the epoch drop list did not get selected, only the frame drop list and input text box get values.

I also tried:

`wget --post-data 'from_frame_in=values&from_epoch_year=values&from_epoch_decimal=values&inputvalues=values&to_frame_out=values&to_epoch_year=values&to_epoch_decimal=values&transform_button=values' "$websiteurl"`.

This script can  make all the drop list and input text box get values.
However for both two methods mentioned above, I don't know how to retrieve the calculated results from the output text box.

I appreciate very much if anyone can help me with that or point me a direction to solve such a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please format your question.

Open page in e.g. Chrome, hit F12, tab Network, Click on Transform (on your web page). Scroll up in Network tab and right click on index.php - Copy - Copy as cURL (bash)
After stripping garbage you should get:

```
curl -s 'http://www.epncb.oma.be/_productsservices/coord_trans/index.php'   --data-raw 'from_frame_in=ETRF89&from_epoch_year=2000&from_epoch_decimal=0&from_epoch_year2=2000&from_epoch_doy=001&from_epoch_date=2000-01-01&from_epoch_week=1042&from_epoch_dow=6&inputvalues=%23+Lines+starting+by+%23+are+treated+as+comments%0D%0A%23+Fields+%28in+decimal+format%29+should+be+separated+by+at+least+one+space%0D%0A%23%0D%0A%23+--%3E+Example+without+velocity+-+StationName%28no+space+character%29+X%5Bm%5D+Y%5Bm%5D+Z%5Bm%5D+%3A%0D%0AStationName+4027894.006+307045.600+4919474.910%0D%0A%23%0D%0A%23+--%3E+Example+with+velocity+-+StationName%28no+space+character%29+X%5Bm%5D+Y%5Bm%5D+Z%5Bm%5D+VX%5Bm%2Fyr%5D+VY%5Bm%2Fyr%5D+VZ%5Bm%2Fyr%5D+%3A%0D%0AStationName+4027894.006+307045.600+4919474.910+0.01+0.2+0.03%0D%0A&to_frame_out=ETRF89&to_epoch_year=2000&to_epoch_decimal=0&to_epoch_year2=2000&to_epoch_doy=001&to_epoch_date=2000-01-01&to_epoch_week=1042&to_epoch_dow=6&outputvalues=StationName+4027894.00600++307045.60000+4919474.91000+%C2%A0+%C2%A0+%C2%A0%0D%0AStationName+4027894.00600++307045.60000+4919474.91000++0.01000++0.20000++0.03000%0D%0A&epochtype=decimalyear&transform_button=Transform'   --compressed   --insecure | xmllint --html --xpath "//textarea[@name='outputvalues']/text()" - 2>/dev/null

StationName 4027894.00600  307045.60000 4919474.91000      
StationName 4027894.00600  307045.60000 4919474.91000  0.01000  0.20000  0.03000
```

`-s` silence curl progress, `xmllint --html --xpath` parse output of curl and clip element in xpath (xmllint can be installed by `sudo apt install libxml2-utils`), `-` tells xmllint take stdin/pipe from curl instead of file, `2>/dev/null` redirect error output to hell - nasty way get rid of parsing errors

Comment: lojza, thank you so much. I followed your method and found my problem is because I forgot to set value with epochtype. Anyway I appreciate your timely reply and suggestion.